# How to mount a FUSE-based filesystem on docker container running on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, fuse, rclone

I need to mount a FUSE-based filesystem (using [rclone](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/)) on a docker container that must be executed on AWS ECS Fargate.

I have no problem running the container locally using the following command:

```
docker run --rm --device /dev/fuse --cap-add SYS_ADMIN <IMAGE_NAME>
```

While on AWS ECS Fargate the docker container is not working properly because I haven't found how to set the flags **--device** and **--cap-add** when I define the task on AWS ECS. Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to find a way to set the flags and run the fargate as you'd like?

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a direct solution to the problem. I've posted the workaround in the hope it may help.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a direct solution to the problem. This is the workaround that I used back then:

I switched to an ECS task of EC2 type because, how you can see in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html), both the flag **--device** and **--cap-add** were and still are not available for tasks launched on Fargate.

In this way, only through the JSON definition of the task, I was able to add
the flags that I needed. Here below a sample json definition that shows how to add these properties:

```
{
  ... other properties
  "containerDefinitions": [
      ... other properties
      "linuxParameters": {
        "capabilities": {
          "add": [
            "SYS_ADMIN"
          ],
          "drop": null
        },
        ... other properties
        "devices": [
          {
            "containerPath": "/dev/fuse",
            "hostPath": "/dev/fuse",
            "permissions": null
          }
        ],
        ... other properties
      },
      ... other properties
  ],
  ... other properties
}
```